# Alternative as NOT IN gives a blank array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a query in my rails application,

```
      user_info = Information.where("user_id = ? and department_id NOT IN (?)",user.id,     Department.unapproved_departments ).all(:include => [:name, :project]).
```

Here unapproved_departments contains an array of ids in Department table.

The problem arises when unapproved_departments is a blank array.In those cases "NOT IN"
checks for ids present in the array and entire user_info is returned as a blank array.
So i would like to have all the data with ids other than those in unapproved_departments array or you can say an alternative for **NOT IN**

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong with NOT IN -- just that you don't want it to fire when there's nothing there.

I suggest:

```
  user_info = Information.where("user_id = ?", user)

  unapproved_departments = Department.unapproved_departments
  if unapproved_departments.present?   # true if not blank or nil
    user_info = user_info.where("department_id NOT IN (?)", unaproved_departments) 
  end
  user_info.all(:include => [:name, :project])
```

As you can see, you can chain the conditions together.

Comment: .thanx ,that's easy one but you get in more of if,else when NOT IN is used multiple times..

Comment: Well using named scopes helps keep it concise:

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just have a special case for when unapproved_departments is empty?

```
if Department.unapproved_departments.empty?
    user_info = Information.where("user_id = ?",user.id).all(:include => [:name, :project])
else
     user_info = Information.where("user_id = ? and department_id NOT IN (?)",user.id,     Department.unapproved_departments ).all(:include => [:name, :project])
end
```

Comment: @fernandes...thanx..nice approach when the condition is to be used once but i have already used NOT IN no of places and did't knew about this problem...

Comment: @GhostRider get those searches to work then ;) I'm not sure you can get an easy solution, but I'm not an expert in neither Rails nor SQL so I can't help much more :(

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you define better unapproved_departments to retun [nil] instead of []

Oterwhise you can add [0] to your code :

```
    user_info = Information.where("user_id = ? and department_id NOT IN (?)",user.id,     (Department.unapproved_departments << 0) ).all(:include => [:name, :project]).
```

Comment: What if there is a department_id of 0?

Comment: thanx ...i know adding [0] or any other no is a solution but here i'm looking for a better approach

Comment: ok, so define better unapproved_departments:
def self.unapproved_departments_normalized
  unapproved_departments.blank? ? [0] : unapproved_departments
end

Answer (score 0):

If we concentrate just on the "NOT IN" part:

```
user_info = Information.where("department_id NOT IN (?)", []).to_sql
# => SELECT `informations`.* from `informations` where department_id not in (NULL)
```

Which is weird because of null-tests: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

What we can do is reverse the test and get the required result:

```
user_info = Information.where("NOT (department_id IN (?))", []).to_sql
# => SELECT `informations`.* from `informations` where NOT (department_id in (NULL))
```

It works because in MySQL everything is != NULL (and also < NULL and > NULL at same time!).

Comment: @adzdavies...i tried user_info = Information.where("NOT (department_id IN (?))", []).to_sql but it too returns [] .thanx